# awk: print duplicates from two files

Tags: linux, awk

File1:

```
23455|abc|xyz
23455|abc|xsd
34433|wer|sad
45655|fdf|fcd
```

File2:

```
v343v|23455
z565z|23455
c9898|34433
b2323|45655
```

Output should be:

```
23455|abc|xyz|v343v
23455|abc|xyz|z565z
23455|abc|xsd|v343v
23455|abc|xsd|z565z
34433|wer|sad|c9898
45655|fdf|fcd|b2323
```

I am using the below command :

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$1"|"$2"|"$3; next} $2 > 0 {print a[$2] "|" $1}' file1 file2 > result.txt
```

But its only showing the result :

```
23455|abc|xsd|v343v
23455|abc|xsd|z565z
34433|wer|sad|c9898
45655|fdf|fcd|b2323
```

Note: Both the files have data in random order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ join -t '|' -2 2 file1 file2
23455|abc|xyz|v343v
23455|abc|xyz|z565z
23455|abc|xsd|v343v
23455|abc|xsd|z565z
34433|wer|sad|c9898
45655|fdf|fcd|b2323
```

This performs a relational JOIN operation on the two files.  The `-t '|'` tells `join` that `|` is used as a field delimiter in the input data, and `-2 2` tells it to use the second field in the second of the two files (rather than the first).

This assumes that the join column is sorted in the two files.

Are they not sorted, then pre-sort the files using

```
sort -t '|' -k1 -o file1 file1
sort -t '|' -k2 -o file2 file2
```

or sort at the same time as you call `join` using a process substitution in  a shell that supports this:

```
join -t '|' -2 2 \
    <( sort -t '|' -k1 file1 ) \
    <( sort -t '|' -k2 file2 )
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.. please note that both the files have random data order.. join statement asks for sorted data..

Comment: @Maddys See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(index(i,$2)==1) print i,$1}' file1 file2
```

The `for` loops trough all lines of file1 stored in the array `a`. If the first element of the second file matches and array entry, print it.